# Portal 2 Closing Scene Does Not Fit With The Rest of The Story

Tags: portal-2

At the end of Portal 2, There's a cut scene which shows your ascent to the surface and to safety. However, this scene doesn't seem to line up with the rest of Portal or Portal 2. At the end of Portal (1), After defeating GLaDOS, you are pulled upward into blinding sunlight and find yourself outside.[image] This seems to show that the surface is right above GLaDOS's chamber. This is reinforced in Portal 2 when defeating Wheatly. After being hit by the bombs Wheatly uses to sabotage the Stalemate resolution button, you are lying on your back when some wall panels fly off revealing the moon.[image]

This would also seem to suggest that the surface is not far from the chamber. How can you take the long elevator ride at the end of Portal 2 when the surface is right above GLaDOS's chamber?

Comment: Clearly it is because of witchcraft.

Comment: @Wipqozn Did you mean: ___aliens___

Comment: What I'm more interested to know is that in Portal, you end up in a parking lot on the surface, and in Portal 2, you appear to be on a farm, with no buildings in site. How big is the underground Aperture Science, and how far did you travel since the first game.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs They're the same room because GLaDOS is in there and the room looks the same as it did when you and Wheatly confront GLaDOS.

Comment: Wipqozn and badp - Clearly it is because of portals.  Duh.

Comment: 'Because they made it that way'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd say it's a case of moving architecture. We see in Portal 2 how entire rooms can be shuffled around the underground without much of a hassle. When GLaDOS started cleaning the place up she probably decided it'd be safer in some way to have her room not directly under the surface. Wheatley probably put it back when he was in control because he's a genius that way; it was then moved back down afterwards.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer, I remember hearing Wheatly talk about how he was moving his "lair".

Comment: Also, remember when you're being tricked to go into the "Cake Dispensary" (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDqJfNjXv_g#t=589s) you aren't even close to the surface.

Answer (score 15):

When you are woken up again by the robots you are in the chamber where the first core transplant takes place. I assume it is because this one has not been destroyed. This chamber is obviously further down.

Also maybe the turrets wanted you to go though their chamber so that they can sing to you.

Comment: Also, Glados could have used the time to get to/build a chamber deeper down...because being close to the surface has a significant disadvantage.